# In Django ORM: Select record from each group with maximal value of a given attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models

Say I have three models as follows representing the prices of goods sold at several retail locations of the same company:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    address = models.TextField()

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    description = models.TextField()

class Price(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    effective_date = models.DateField()
    value = models.FloatField()
```

When a price is set, it is set on a store-and-product-specific basis.  I.e. the same item can have different prices in different stores.  And each of these prices has an effective date.  For a given `store` and a given `product`, the currently-effective price is the one with the latest `effective_date`.

What's the best way to write the query that will return the currently-effective price of all items in all stores?

If I were using Pandas, I would get myself a dataframe with columns `['store', 'product', 'effective_date', 'price']` and I would run

```
dataframe\
    .sort_values(columns=['store', 'product', 'effective_date'], ascending=[True, True, False])\
    .groupby('store', 'product')['price'].first()
```

But there has to be some way of doing this directly on the database level.  Thoughts?

Comment: if you want a list of items and the `effective_date` is your main requirement then you need  something like `Product.objects.distinct().filter(...).order_by('-price__effective_date')`

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your DBMS is PostgreSQL you can use *distinct* combined with *order_by* this way :

```
Price.objects.order_by('store','product','-effective_date').distinct('store','product')
```

It will give you all the latest prices for all product/store combinations.

There are tricks about *distinct*, have a look at the docs here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PostgreSQL, you could use [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) and [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to get the current effective prices for all the products in all the stores as follows:

```
prices = Price.objects.order_by('store', 'product', '-effective_date')
                      .distinct('store', 'product')
```

Now, this is quite analogous to what you have there for `Pandas`.

Do note that using field names in `distinct` only works in PostgreSQL. Once you have sorted the prices based on `store`, `product` and decreasing order of `effective date`, `distinct('store', 'product')` will retain only the first entry for each store-product pair and that will be your current entry with recent price.

---

**Not PostgreSQL database:**

If you are not using PostgreSQL, you could do it with two queries:

First, we get latest effective date for all the `store-product` groups:

```
latest_effective_dates = Price.objects.values('store_id', 'product_id')
                             .annotate(led=Max('effective_date')).values('led')
```

Once we have these dated we could get the prices for this date:

```
prices = Price.objects.filter(effective_date__in=latest_effective_dates)
```

*Disclaimer:* This assumes that for no `effective_date` is same for any `store-product` group.

Comment: Your non-postgres solution fails, however, if any price has a date that happens to be the same as the latest date of another store-product-combination.

Comment: Thanks, it seems I did miss that part. I updated my disclaimer.

Answer (score 1):

Without Postgres' added power (which you should really use) there is a more complicated solution to this (based on [ryanpitts' idea](https://gist.github.com/ryanpitts/1304725)), which requires two db hits:

```
latest_set = Price.objects
    .values('store_id', 'product_id')  # important to have values before annotate ...
    .annotate(max_date=Max('effective_date')).order_by()
    # ... to annotate for the grouping that results from values

# Build a query that reverse-engineers the Price records that contributed to 
# 'latest_set'. (Relying on the fact that there are not 2 Prices
# for the same product-store with an identical date)

q_statement = Q(product_id=-1)  # sth. that results in empty qs
for latest_dict in latest_set:          
    q_statement |= 
        (Q(product_id=latest_dict['product_id']) & 
         Q(store_id=latest_dict['store_id']) & 
         Q(effective_date=latest_dict['max_date']))

Price.objects.filter(q_statement)
```